# Add child object with value to existing javaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have an empty root object created in JavsScript:

```
var myObject = {};
```

Now, I want to add a child object with a value:

```
{  
   "myObject ":{  
      "myChildObject":"FooBar"
   }
}
```

Seems simple enough, but I'm having a hard time finding an answer.  Most of the examples I find are related to DOM objects (div's) and don't really translate well.  I've been looking at [W3Schools on their .appendChild() page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp), but the examples there don't set a value.

Comment: `myObject.myObject.myChildObject = 'FooBar';`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`myObject.myChildObject = 'foo'`

or, if your key has spaces in it you can use square bracket notation:

`myObject['my Child Object'] = 'foo'`

Answer (score 3):

If You want to add a child to myObject then just do it

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.myChildObject = "Foo Bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.myObject = Object.assign({myChildObject:"red"});
console.log(myObject);
```

Result:

```
{  
   "myObject ":{  
      "myChildObject":"FooBar"
   }
}
```